# header files in iks01a2_conf.h template

Tags: c, stm32, include-path, nucleo

I was trying to use code generated by STM32CubeMX. I've generated project for SW4STM32, but I have problem with iks01a2_conf_template.h file. Im supposed to replace the header file names with the ones of the target platform and rename the file to iks01a2_conf. 
There are 3 headers:

```
#include "stm32yyxx_hal.h"
#include "nucleo_xyyyzz_bus.h"
#include "nucleo_xyyyzz_errno.h"
```

I changed first one to "stm32f1xx_hal.h", but I don't know what to do with rest of them. I've tried several names but none of them were found. **What are the header files i'm supposed to use there?**
My hardware is: STM32F103RB and X-NUCLEO-IKS01A2. When it comes to expansion board i need to use LPS22HB barometer to measure pressure and temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `inc` project folder. Your files shuold be there.

Add this folder to the include directories in your project settings or makefile

[image]